# Angular 5 don't stop sending request in iframe

Tags: javascript, angular, iframe

I'm trying to show pdf file in iframe tag in angular 5. And I get it, but in some reason iframe sends requests to server again and again every 2-3 secods. After it my pdf document in iframe reloads. Is anybody knows why it happens?

```
// Here is my HTML
<iframe *ngIf="currentArticle.text === null" width="100%" height="100%" [src]="getUrl(currentArticle.id)" type="application/pdf"></iframe>
```

```
// My component.ts
public getUrl(id)
    {
        return this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl('api/v1/support_files/' + id);
    }
```

```
// Server side Node js
function support(req, res){
    try {
        const folderName = process.cwd() + '/' + process.env.SUPPORT_FOLDER

        return res.sendFile(`${folderName}/${req.params.id}.pdf`);
    } catch (error){
        console.log(error);
        return res.status(500).json({
            message: error.message
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: include relevant code of the component which host you iframe pls

Comment: It is very big. I included function that sanitize URL for iframe src. What I need to add there?

Comment: could be changedetection problem, cause you call the url with a method

Answer (score 0):

There is mistake that I use function getUrl as src for Iframe. That's why Angular reloads Iframe.

```
// HTML
<iframe *ngIf="currentArticle.text === null" width="100%" height="100%" [src]="currentArticleSrc" type="application/pdf"></iframe>
```

And set currentArticleSrc in component.ts

```
// Component.ts
public currentArticleUrl: SafeResourceUrl;

setArticleUrl(article: Article) {
        this.currentArticleUrl = article.text === null ?
            this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl( `${backendRestUrl}support_files/${article.id}`)
        : null;
    }
```

Now it works well